# Connecting two models in many-to-many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have a problem. 
I want to get all matches in my player#show where player was engaged. So I did a many-to-many relationship.

Match model:

```
class Match < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :match_schedules
  has_many :players, through: :match_schedules
end
```

Player model:

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :match_schedules
  has_many :matches, through: :match_schedules
  has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

and my match_schedule model:

```
class MatchSchedule < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :player
  belongs_to :match
end
```

If i do something like this in rails console:

```
p = Player.find 1
m = p.matches.new
m.playerA = “leo”
m.playerB = “cris”
p.save
```

It works, i can display loop with name:

```
<% @player.matches.each do |match| %>
<%= match.playerA %>
<% end %>
```

Problem is that i don't really know how I can connect matches to player in my new form, in browser. Already i have something like this:
Players_helper:

```
module PlayersHelper
  def player_hash(players)
    hash = Hash.new
    players.each do |player|
      hash["#{player.first_name}" + " " + "#{player.last_name}"] = player.first_name + player.last_name
    end
    hash
  end
end
```

and _form:

```
  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.select :playerA, options_for_select(player_hash(@abc)) %>
    <%= f.select :playerB, options_for_select(player_hash(@abc)) %>
    <%= f.input :PlayerApoints %>
    <%= f.input :PlayerBpoints %>
  </div>
```

Matches controller for new and create method looks like:

```
  def new
    @match = Match.new
    @abc = Player.all
  end
  def create
    @match = Match.new(match_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @match.save
        format.html { redirect_to @match, notice: 'Match was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @match }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @match.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

And my schema.rb:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150706185030) do
create_table "match_schedules", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "match_id"
    t.integer  "player_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
create_table "matches", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "playerA"
    t.string   "playerB"
    t.integer  "PlayerApoints"
    t.integer  "PlayerBpoints"
    t.datetime "created_at",    null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",    null: false
  end
create_table "players", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.datetime "created_at",          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",          null: false
    t.string   "avatar_file_name"
    t.string   "avatar_content_type"
    t.integer  "avatar_file_size"
    t.datetime "avatar_updated_at"
  end
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

Comment: You have a separate table for Match and Match Schedule, its that really needed? If so you should not have a player_id in your match schedule, just a match_id. Or the other way around, you should just have the score in the Match table, and there would be two entries for each match in the Match Schedule table, identifying each player. You tables need to be normalized to remove that redundant data and make the relationships clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You left out your match_params hash, so I have to do some guessing but something along the lines of:
in your Match class:

```
class Match < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :match_schedules
  has_many :players, through: :match_schedules
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :match_schedules
end
```

in your controller:

```
def new
  @match = Match.new
  @match.match_schedules.build
  @abc = Player.all
end

def create
    @match = Match.new(match_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @match.save
        format.html { redirect_to @match, notice: 'Match was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @match }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @match.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

in your match_params whitelist you'll need to add:

```
..., :player_ids => [])
```

since it is an array you need to put it after the other params.

You will also have to modify your view code. Basically you want to return a `match_shedules_attributes => {player_ids => [1,2]}` this gives you the ability to tell the `MatchSchedule` table the ID of each player associated with that `match_id`. You can do this with a `fields_for` inside the `form_for` block. See this http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html

So in the `create` action in the Match controller it should also save two records in the MatchSchedule table, one with each player's id and the id of that match.

Comment: `fields_for` is really the key here. I will add a `hidden_field` with the id of the Match in it, that will get associated with the player_id.

Comment: Could you give me a example how i should do that? I did something like this:   <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.hidden_field :match_schedules %>
    <%= f.select :playerA, options_for_select(player_hash(@abc)) %>
    <%= f.select :playerB, options_for_select(player_hash(@abc)) %>
    <%= f.input :PlayerApoints %>
    <%= f.input :PlayerBpoints %>
  </div>

and still in my SQLite Database Browser i can't see any data in my match_schedules table.

Comment: and btw with your Match model fix i cant even add matches to players in rails console

Comment: It is impossible to read code that big in the comments. Please update your question. I have not worked out every detail in my answer, mostly because I don't have a working copy to test anything. If you want me to be more specific I'd have to have a repository that I could clone and use.

Comment: As I said above, you really need to use `fields_for` inside your `form_for` loop. If you don't understand how to use `fields_for` you won't be able to code more complex forms with nested parameters. I don't see why the addition of `accepts_nested_attributes_for` would break your Match model. If you remove that does the code work again?